# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency for stylelint tree while upgrading to new version

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, dependency-management, stylelint

I upgraded to a new node version(v16.16.0) and npm version(8.11.0). I already deleted node modules and package-lock.json before `npm install`. But when I tried `npm install` got this error:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: stylelint@13.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/stylelint
npm ERR!   stylelint@"^13.7.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer stylelint@"^8.0.0" from stylelint-config-standard@17.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/stylelint-config-standard
npm ERR!   stylelint-config-standard@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution
```

This was the dependency version in `package.json`:

```
"stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^0.10.5",
"stylelint": "^13.7.2",
```

I tried changing it to `17.0.0` but the following still did not work.

```
"stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^0.10.5",
"stylelint": "^17.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 8 of npm will warn when peer dependencies aren't met, e.g. the version of stylelint defined as a peer dependency in stylelint-config-standard isn't being met.

You should update all the stylelint-related dependencies together:

`npm i -D stylelint@latest stylelint-config-standard@latest stylelint-webpack-plugin@latest`